# How can I use MPTVOutWindow iPhone undocumented class?

Tags: iphone

I'm an iPhone developer, now I'm developing a game and I just found about the iPhone 2.2 being able to reproduce video on a TV Screen trhough `MPTVOutWindow` class. After googling I've found a lot of blogs with the News, however none of them give any information on the class,

what should I do to implement the class in order to display ouput on the TV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No luck from stackoverflow, but I found these links in case it comes in hany for someone:
http://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2009/11/26/iphone-tv-out-tutorial/
http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-app-video-out/

Answers like: apple's gonna chase you down and hunt you in your dreams don't help.

Answer (score -1):

You generally shouldn't use this class. It is undocumented, unsupposrted, has changed incompatibly between iPhone OS release. Using it will cause Apple to reject your application.

Comment: actually my app is on cydia, so it wouldn't matter, I'll compile against iPhone OS 2.2

Comment: There is no guarantee that it will work on a 3.x device, even if you build against 2.2.