# Record iPhone app video (without simulator)

Tags: iphone, video, capture, screen-capture, recording

How can I record a video of an iPhone app? I can't use the Simulator because the application is very OpenGL-heavy and uses an accelerometer/gyroscope.

Comment: Depending on your needs, consider simply making a good-quality "home" video.  (example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZGDusXgFOg )  Today, any reasonably good camcorder is basically professional grade.  The only cinematography tip you need: make sure you learn how to lock-off both the **focus, and exposure**, on the handycam.  A good tripod is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the iphone output video and capture on another device: [How can I use MPTVOutWindow iPhone undocumented class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671926/how-can-i-use-mptvoutwindow-iphone-undocumented-class)

one of the links in that answer says it doesn't work in iOS4+, but on a project I worked on less than one month ago, we used that feature from an iPhone4 to present, so I would challenge that (unless the developer that handled that portion used another approach)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a "native" solution here, short of building video capture into your actual app.

The cleanest way of handling this, assuming your game/app has a cleanly designed input pipeline, is probably to mock the input:

- Put in (debug-only code) that lets you "record" all the raw input events.
- Using the device, play out the demo session to create a "recording".
- Run the app in the simulator, and feed it the input "recording" you made on the device.

The simulator will run GL stuff just fine, and probably at a higher framerate than your device will.

Comment: Well, I really can't do this. In some functions I use ARM NEON assembly and porting this back to x86 would be painful.

Comment: @John: Fair enough. I would recommend editing your question to make it clear that you the reason you can't use the simulator isn't just because you use the e.g. gyroscope for input; it's because your app fundamentally isn't compatible with the simulator at all.